# Move to next row of table via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code to check the value of each cell within the range in sheet17 that isn't blank against another range of data within Sheet1. If the value isn't found in sheet1 then the cell value and various cells to its left and right are transferred into sheet2.
This works well however you can see that the code is only set up to populate row 2 on sheet2. I need the code to step down a row in sheet2 for each successful iteration of the loop.
I have the LRow line of code but i dont think i'm using it correctly.
Any assistance / guidance would be great

```
        Sub Induction_Report2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

  Sheet2.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

Dim s As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Integer

Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


  For i = 79 To 6256
   If Cells(i, 15) <> "" Then
  Set s = Sheet1.Range("A1:A9000").Find(What:=Sheet17.Cells(i, 15).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'SEARCH FOR NAME AND SUPPLIER WITHIN INDUCTION LIST
    If s Is Nothing Then 'name is not found
Sheet2.Range("C2").Value = Sheet17.Cells(i, 11).Value 'Transfer name
Sheet2.Range("B2").Value = Sheet17.Cells(i, 14).Value 'Transfer Role
Sheet2.Range("D2").Value = Sheet17.Cells(i, 12).Value 'Transfer Supplier
Sheet2.Range("A2").Value = Sheet17.Cells(i, 16).Value 'Transfer Job Number
     End If
     End If
     lRow = lRow + 1
     Next i
     
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't add 1 to lRow every iteration since you'll only want to increase it when you're actually adding data (when it passes the second If statement) and the lRow should be used in your Range as follows:

```
lRow = lRow+1 'so you don't overwrite your last row
For i = 79 To 6256 'hardcoding like this is ill-advised; you can also use a lRow variation for this sort of thing but that's not your question right now
   If Cells(i, 15) <> "" Then
       Set s = Sheet1.Range("A1:A9000").Find(What:=Sheet17.Cells(i, 15).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'SEARCH FOR NAME AND SUPPLIER WITHIN INDUCTION LIST
       If s Is Nothing Then 'name is not found
           Sheet2.Range("C" & lRow).Value = Sheet17.Cells(i, 11).Value 'Transfer name
           Sheet2.Range("B" & lRow).Value = Sheet17.Cells(i, 14).Value 'Transfer Role
           Sheet2.Range("D" & lRow).Value = Sheet17.Cells(i, 12).Value 'Transfer Supplier
           Sheet2.Range("A" & lRow).Value = Sheet17.Cells(i, 16).Value 'Transfer Job Number
           lRow = lRow + 1
       End If
    End If
Next i
```

Hope this helps :)

Ps: I just noticed you clear the content of your rows 2 and onwards so you could just have used `lRow = 2` (without my added `lRow = lRow + 1` in front of your for loop)

Comment: Hi again Notus_Panda. Can you elaborate on your 'hardcoding' point. I'd like to look at alternatives

Comment: Hardcoding means setting the values there yourself instead of looking up through something like you did with the lRow. What are the conditions of your Sheet17, why start at 79 and end at 6256? If 6256 is the last row in Sheet17, you can do the same as you did with lRow for example.

Comment: could you show me that in the code? I've had to use the hardcoding method alot and it does cause issues

Comment: and yes row 6256 is the last possible row of the range of data that i want to code to look at. there is data above and below it that i want the code to ignore

Comment: Sadly enough, if you have data above (I'm assuming rows 2-78 or possibly even 1-78) and after (6257 and onwards), then hardcoding is the only way unless you give me some logic as for how to determine these barriers?

Answer (score 1):

### A VBA Lookup (`Application.Match`)

[image]

```
Sub CreateInductionReport()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const LKP_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2" ' 2.) ... here, if no match...
    Const SRC_RANGE As String = "O79:O6256" ' 1.) Lookup this...
    Const SRC_COLS As String = "P,N,K,L" ' 3.) ... copy these...
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2" ' 4.) ... here.
    
    ' Reference the worksheets (using code names).
    
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = Sheet1 ' Lookup
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Sheet17 ' Source
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Sheet2 ' Destination
    
    ' Reference the lookup range.
    
    Dim lfCell As Range: Set lfCell = lws.Range(LKP_FIRST_CELL)
    Dim llCell As Range: Set llCell = lfCell.Resize( _
        lws.Rows.Count - lfCell.Row + 1).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = lws.Range(lfCell, llCell)
    
    ' Reference the source range.
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(SRC_RANGE)
    Dim slCell As Range
    Set slCell = srg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    Set srg = sws.Range(srg.Cells(1), slCell)
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    ' Write the values from the source columns to the source jagged array.
    
    Dim sCols() As String: sCols = Split(SRC_COLS, ",") ' zero-based
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(sCols) + 1 ' one-based
    Dim sJag(): ReDim sJag(1 To cCount)
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    For c = 1 To cCount
        sJag(c) = srg.EntireRow.Columns(sCols(c - 1)).Value
    Next c
    
    ' Write the source row indexes, of the matches of the source range
    ' in the lookup range, to the source rows array. Values with no match,
    ' the values of interest will return error values
    
    Dim srData(): srData = Application.Match(srg, lrg, 0)
    
    ' Define the destination array.
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = srCount - Application.Count(srData)
    If drCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no missing values in the source worksheet.", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    ' Write the values from the source jagged array, not found in the lookup
    ' range i.e. defined by the error values in the source rows array,
    ' to the destination array.
    
    Dim sr As Long, dr As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        If IsError(srData(sr, 1)) Then ' no match
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dData(dr, c) = sJag(c)(sr, 1)
            Next c
        'Else ' is a match; do nothing
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Reference the destination range.
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(drCount, cCount)
    
    ' Write the values from the destination array to the destination range
    ' and clear below
    
    drg.Value = dData
    drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - drCount + 1).Offset(drCount).Clear
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Induction report created.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: The reason you're clearing after filling in the data is to minimize the time needed to clear, I presume? Since OP was clearing the entire row, I figured there were perhaps some side-calculations in other columns on that sheet as well but that's easily adjustable in your code. I'm actually in the process of doing something similar so it's nice to have an example if I get stuck somewhere.

Comment: Yes, the idea is it should be more efficient. It probably largely depends on the underlying data. I tested it once or twice but the gain was measured in milliseconds or even microseconds. Nothing to write home about. What you need to take from this answer is that the `Find` method cannot compete with `Application.Match`. Even more so because of the killer blow: `srData = Application.Match(srg, lrg, 0)`. a single line returning the matching row indexes or error values in a 2D one-based single-column array.

Comment: Hmm, trying to follow your way with `Application.Match` but wouldn't `srCount` and `Application.Count(srData)` be the same? At least on my end it's saying the amount of rows in my range is the same as the amount in srData since it includes the errors (I edited a few cells so they couldn't be found to be sure about that)

Comment: `srCount` is all rows, while `Application.Count(srData)` is the count of all rows minus the count of everything that is not a number. In this case, there are row indexes which are whole numbers (integers), and error values. If you subtract this latter count from `srCount` you get the number of error values that is `drCount`. So you have actually detected a flaw in my code i.e. if there are no error values the code will fail because `drCount` will be `0`.

Comment: Ok, glad to be of use and sorry for the confusion, noticed my mistake as well, simple head-calculation error. Thanks for the explanation regardless :)

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest. Thanks for the upvote. I noticed you being pretty active lately. I also had to upvote your previous answer (`Split`). One might say nothing special about it but I liked how you put it into words. Keep up the good work and feel free to ask or comment (good or bad) on any of my answers.