# Consolidating Data through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have created an VBA code which helps me in consolidating the data from different different workbooks and paste into my targetsheet while pasting the data it is pasting the formulas and because of the #REF! is coming in all the cells i want to paste my data in PasteAsspecial.

```
Sub ConsolidateData()

    Dim sourcePath As String
    Dim folderName As Variant
    Dim sourceFile As String
    Dim SourceBook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim targetRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    'Set the path to the source Directory
    sourcePath = "C:\Windows\Blackstone\Software\Box\Internal Control\L1 & L2 Review Project\Checklist"

    'Set the target sheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview")

    'Copy Column headers to target sheet if it's empty
    If Application.CountA(targetSheet.Range("A1:XFD1")) = 0 Then
        targetSheet.Range("A1:XFD1").Value = Array("Tab Name", "Activity", "SOP Status", "CQ Quarter Transition", "Quarter of Transition", "Source Systems", "Exclusions/Exceptions", "Comments", "Criticality", "Time spent L1 (mins)", "Est. Time Spent L2 (mins)", "L2 Applicable")
        End If

    'Loop through each folder in the source directory
    For Each folderName In Array("Asia Business Finance", "Asia Finance I PM", "BEPIF FPA", "BPP Finance", "BREDS AM", "BREDS Loan Ops", "BREIT FP&A and PM", "BREP Finance", "Common Activities", "EMEA PM", "Europe PM", "US PM")
        'set the path to the source folder
        sourcePath = "C:\Windows\Blackstone\Software\Box\Internal Control\L1 & L2 Review Project\Checklist\Chicklist2\" & folderName & "\"

        'Loop through each file in the source folder
        sourceFile = Dir(sourcePath & "*.xlsx")
        Do While sourceFile <> ""
            'Open the sourceWorkbook
            Set SourceBook = Workbooks.Open(sourcePath & sourceFile)

            'set the source sheet
            Set sourceSheet = SourceBook.Worksheets("Overview")

            'Find the last row in the source sheet
            lastrow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            'loop through each row in the source sheet
            For i = 2 To lastrow
    
                'Check if the row meets the criteria for copying
                If sourceSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value <> "" Then

                    'copy the row to the target sheet
                    targetRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    sourceSheet.Range("A" & i & ":L" & i).Copy targetSheet.Range("B" & targetRow & ":M" & targetRow)
                    targetSheet.Cells(targetRow, "A").Value = folderName 'Add folder name to column A
                End If
            Next i

            'Close the sourceWorkbook
            SourceBook.Close

            'Get the next file in the directory
            sourceFile = Dir
        Loop
    Next folderName

    'Save the target workbook
    ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: @brax did not get any changes in your answer, can you please provide this again

Comment: I did not provide an answer. I edited the question so it was formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and easy way to get the paste special:

```
sourceSheet.Range("A" & i & ":L" & i).Copy 
targetSheet.Range("B" & targetRow & ":M" & targetRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

But you could as well use:

```
targetSheet.Range("B" & targetRow & ":M" & targetRow).Value = sourceSheet.Range("A" & i & ":L" & i).Value
```

The faster way would be with arrays so you're not adding row per row:

```
Sub ConsolidateData()
    
    Const COL_AMT = 13 'amount of col A-M
    Dim sourcePath As String
    Dim folderName As Variant
    Dim sourceFile As String
    Dim SourceBook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lRowT As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, rCount As Long
    Dim arr(), arrT()

    'Set the path to the source Directory
    sourcePath = "C:\Windows\Blackstone\Software\Box\Internal Control\L1 & L2 Review Project\Checklist"

    'Set the target sheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview")

    'Copy Column headers to target sheet if it's empty
    If Application.CountA(targetSheet.Range("A1:XFD1")) = 0 Then
        targetSheet.Range("A1:XFD1").Value = Array("Tab Name", "Activity", "SOP Status", "CQ Quarter Transition", "Quarter of Transition", "Source Systems", "Exclusions/Exceptions", "Comments", "Criticality", "Time spent L1 (mins)", "Est. Time Spent L2 (mins)", "L2 Applicable")
    End If

    'Loop through each folder in the source directory
    For Each folderName In Array("Asia Business Finance", "Asia Finance I PM", "BEPIF FPA", "BPP Finance", "BREDS AM", "BREDS Loan Ops", "BREIT FP&A and PM", "BREP Finance", "Common Activities", "EMEA PM", "Europe PM", "US PM")
        'set the path to the source folder
        sourcePath = "C:\Windows\Blackstone\Software\Box\Internal Control\L1 & L2 Review Project\Checklist\Chicklist2\" & folderName & "\"

        'Loop through each file in the source folder
        sourceFile = Dir(sourcePath & "*.xlsx")
        Do While sourceFile <> ""
            'Open the sourceWorkbook
            Set SourceBook = Workbooks.Open(sourcePath & sourceFile)

            'set the source sheet
            Set sourceSheet = SourceBook.Worksheets("Overview")

            'Find the last row in the source sheet
            lastrow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            lRowT = targetSheet.Range("A" & targetSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get the lRow of the targetSheet once per loop
            arr = sourceSheet.Range("A2:L" & lastrow).Value 'place all needed data in array
            ReDim arrT(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To COL_AMT) '
            'loop through each row in the source sheet
            For i = 1 To lastrow - 1 'arr starts at 1
    
                'Check if the row meets the criteria for copying
                If arr(i, 1) <> "" Then
                    rCount = rCount + 1
                    arrT(rCount, 1) = folderName
                    For j = 2 To COL_AMT
                        arrT(rCount, j) = arr(i, j - 1)
                    Next j
                End If
            Next i
            targetSheet.Range("A" & lRowT).Offset(1).Resize(rCount, COL_AMT).Value = arrT 'get the needed rows in your targetsheet in one go
            'Close the sourceWorkbook
            SourceBook.Close

            'Get the next file in the directory
            sourceFile = Dir
        Loop
    Next folderName

    'Save the target workbook
    ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

(don't forget I did edit/add some of the variables)
Hope that works for you :)

Comment: i am getting break on this line of code ->  lRowT = targetSheet.Cells("A" & targetSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get the lRow of the targetSheet once per loop

Comment: My bad, I'm more used of using `.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row` for last row rather than the .Cells variant and didn't notice it when I typed it in your full sub. It's edited.

Comment: Thanks it actually helps, also can you find me the way which helps me in adding the new data which is being added recently basically which was not available earlier and when we run the code again it should suppose to add that new data only to the table

Comment: As in, you want to only add new entries from the different workbooks to your master workbook? Because that's a whole different question but iirc, I do have [a saved answer about using Application.Match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75627716/19353309) that should help you on your way.

Comment: yes, so i want that my code will only add the new entries which was not available earlier when we run the code again

Comment: Like I said, you'll have to check what you have already which can be done with `Application.Match` like shown in the answer provided in my earlier comment or by using Dictionaries (but in this case the first option would likely be faster). This would require you to have certain keys/unique values of course (or any way to determine whether it's new (to be added) or old (to be ignored) data).