# VBA Copy Data to another sheet if not already in sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, criteria, paste

I'm very new to VBA.

My coding currently copies a report from one sheet (Rufus Unal) to another (UTM Unal Cash Report), I would like it to only copy data that isn’t already on the other sheet. using Column A as the criteria as this contains unique references. So if values in column A are in Sheet (Rufus Unal) and not in sheet (UTM Unal Cash Report) then copy range below last line of data.

Here is my current code:

```
Sub RunUac()

Dim LR1 As Long
Dim LR2 As Long
Dim LR3 As Long
Dim LR4 As Long
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets("Rufus Unal").Visible = True


Workbooks.Open "K:\Finance\Unallocated Cash\Reconciliations\Templates/Rufus_Unal.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True


Workbooks("Rufus_Unal.xlsx").Activate

Sheets("UCRR001x").Activate

LR1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

Range("A2:O" & LR1).Copy

    wb1.Activate
    Sheets("Rufus Unal").Select
    Range("A11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
   
Workbooks("Rufus_Unal.xlsx").Activate

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Sheets("GL").Select
    Range("Sheet16[[#Headers],[Accnt.]]").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    
Sheets("Rufus Unal").Select
    LR1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row

Range("A11:A" & LR1).Copy
    Sheets("UTM Unal Cash Report").Select
    Range("A10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Rufus Unal").Select
Range("I11:I" & LR1).Copy
    Sheets("UTM Unal Cash Report").Select
    Range("B10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
Sheets("Rufus Unal").Select
Range("D11:D" & LR1).Copy
    Sheets("UTM Unal Cash Report").Select
    Range("C10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Rufus Unal").Select
Range("B11:B" & LR1).Copy
    Sheets("UTM Unal Cash Report").Select
    Range("D10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Rufus Unal").Select
Range("C11:C" & LR1).Copy
    Sheets("UTM Unal Cash Report").Select
    Range("E10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    

Sheets("Sign Off Form").Select
     Range("C31").Value = Application.UserName
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I tried copying the range and then removing duplicates but couldn't get it to worked and wondered if its possibly to instead only copy data that is not already on the 'UTM Unal Cash Report' sheet using column A as a criteria to check in each sheet.

Comment: Using `Application.Match` on two ranges gives you the rows that do not have a match -> the ones you'd want to add, see [vBasic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75627716/19353309) on how to do this. Or you can use a dictionary but the Match version is wee bit quicker normally.

Comment: You can go one by one from your first sheet and find the unique reference in other sheet. If it isn't there you can copy the data in last row of other tab.
Current code is quite extensive and most selection part is un-necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as starting approach for your code:

```
Sub RunUac()


'Declarions
Dim LR1 As Long
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

''' Clearly set the workbooks used below like

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("K:\Finance\Unallocated Cash\Reconciliations\Templates/Rufus_Unal.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)

'' Similarly set the worksheets used below

Set ws1 = wb2.Sheets("Name of the sheet")

'''Check the rows in first sheet

LR1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

'''' See if data is present in other sheet, if yes, you can copy the data

loop comes here



End Sub
```

This is still long way from the full code required, but no one here will write it for you. You can start with these instructions and if you face more issues, you can post here.

Comment: thank you both for this! i have managed to sort this now with you help, kind regards