# VBA xlookup in a LOOP

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I am working on a spreadsheet that takes multiple supplier price lists in different formats and creates a single consolidated sheet in a common format.

Once the common file is created if I then get an updated price list from a supplier it checks against the master file and if the item is not found it is flagged as NEW and if the item has changed price it is flagged as UPDATE.

The members gave me a couple of different what-to-do this but at the time it only catered for the adding of new items.  Code is below.... could someone help with the addition code needed to do the update? I have tried to understand how this code works as I though I may be able to copy the routine and updated it - but I am quite new to VBA and my skills are basic at the moment! I think i could figure out how to construct the Xlookup but am stuck as to how i would fit it in to the code below..

The key file in the fromtable is in column D and A in the Totable - field to update are

```
E to B  
K to H  
L to I   
M to J   
N to K
```

I did try this before in another routine but must have done something wrong in the loop as it just kept looping

Really appreciate your help!

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateMasterSupplier()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Update Master Supplier"
    Const FIRST_COLUMN As Long = 2
    Const COLUMNS_COUNT As Long = 2 ' 15 in your case according to comments
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = MapAndValidation
    Dim slo As ListObject: Set slo = sws.ListObjects("MAV_Table")
    
    Dim srg As Range:
    
    With slo
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="New"
        With .DataBodyRange.Columns(FIRST_COLUMN).Resize(, COLUMNS_COUNT)
            On Error Resume Next
                Set srg = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End With
    
    If srg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No matching data found.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = MasterSupplierFile
    Dim dlo As ListObject: Set dlo = dws.ListObjects("MSF_Table")
    
    Dim drrg As Range:
    
    With dlo
        If .ListRows.Count = 0 Then
            Set drrg = .HeaderRowRange.Offset(1).Resize(, COLUMNS_COUNT)
        Else
            With .Range
                Set drrg = .Resize(1, COLUMNS_COUNT).Offset(.Rows.Count)
            End With
        End If
    End With
    
    Dim sarg As Range, sarCount As Long
    
    For Each sarg In srg.Areas
        sarCount = sarg.Rows.Count
        drrg.Resize(sarCount).Value = sarg.Value
        Set drrg = drrg.Offset(sarCount)
    Next sarg
    
    MsgBox "Update complete.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```

I did try writing an Update routine like this before but must have done something wrong in the loop as it just kept looping and I am not sure I was doing it the most efficient way!

Comment: This is just a copy paste from VBasic's answer, where's your attempt to update? In the comments you also mentioned you had updated the columns for it to work so please give us the update on that as well.

Comment: My update attempt was in a an earlier copy of my spreadsheet and I deleted it as it wasn't working... I didn't used the Xlookup up though - I wss finding an UPDATE type in the FROM file and then running a DO Loop over the to file till I found a match ...as the to file could have 1000,s of rows this would not be effecient of practical

Comment: VBasic would maybe opt for having the necessary columns of the from-file in a jagged-array, do a [Application.match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75627716/19353309) of the To-file on the From-file and check if the status is update and if it isn't an error (unlike what he did in the link) and Update, update the data. Not sure if he changed his tactics as of late.

Comment: thanks the link to the application match with comments helps!  I will see if I can come up with a solution - maybe back for more help though !  Appreciate your time thanks again

Comment: I have copied this procedure and created a new update one ... so am i correct that is basically the same process apart from in the FOR EACH SARG loop i replace drrg.Resize(sarCount).Value = sarg.Value
        Set drrg = drrg.Offset(sarCount) with the Xlookup and update of the field code? and change the column const at top

Comment: You'll need to match where the keys are in the To-file so it'll be different than simply replacing that part. Update your question so it's more clear. Perhaps an example of your from-file and your to-file as well.

Comment: pic added - i just realise it will be a lookup so I can get the row number then use the row number and cols to do the updated... in image 1-saved is the destination and 2-saved is the sources - matching on D and A - updating e to b, k to h, L to I, M to J, N to K

Comment: if you can please provide some guidance on this as I am struggling - this code is above my skill level... i get the bit upto setting the filter . then I get lost! All i need to do is process the records filtered - if there is a match on the to file then update the required columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was getting late so I'm sorry @Vbasic2008 if I butchered your code a bit..
Not the cleanest but it got the job done (on my end)

Only thing I edited on Vbasic's code was adding `ChangeUpdated` right above
`MsgBox "Update complete.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE`

```
Sub ChangeUpdated()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Update Master Supplier"
    Const FIRST_COLUMN As Long = 4
    Const COLUMNS_COUNT As Long = 11 ' 15 in your case according to comments
    Dim arrSrc, arrCols, arrDest
    arrCols = Array(2, 8, 9, 10, 11) 'we could shorten  this by just resizing
    arrDest = Array(1, 7, 8, 9, 10) 'but this is to show you how to do it for multiple columns
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = MapAndValidation
    Dim slo As ListObject: Set slo = sws.ListObjects("MAV_Table")
    
    Dim srg As Range:
    
    With slo
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Update"
        With .DataBodyRange.Columns(FIRST_COLUMN)
            On Error Resume Next
                Set srg = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End With
    
    If srg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No matching data found.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = MasterSupplierFile
    Dim dlo As ListObject: Set dlo = dws.ListObjects("MSF_Table")
    
    Dim drrg As Range:
    
    With dlo
        If .ListRows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Nothing to update", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Set drrg = .DataBodyRange.Range("A1").Resize(.ListRows.Count)
        End If
    End With
    
    Dim sarg As Range, sarCount As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, forceArr
    
    For Each sarg In srg.Areas
        arrSrc = Application.Match(sarg, drrg, 0)
        sarCount = sarg.Rows.Count
        If sarCount = 1 Then
            forceArr = arrSrc
            ReDim arrSrc(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            arrSrc(1, 1) = forceArr
        End If
        For i = 1 To sarCount
            If IsError(arrSrc(i, 1)) Then
                Debug.Print "Key not found to update for: " & sarg.Cells(i, 1)
            Else
                For j = 0 To UBound(arrCols)
                    drrg.Cells(arrSrc(i, 1), arrCols(j)).Value = sarg.Cells(i, 1).Offset(, arrDest(j)).Value
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
    Next sarg
End Sub
```

Probably way longer than it needed to be but oh well.

Comment: thanks really appreciate it - I did manage to knock something up to as I was struggling to work out how the array processing worked,

Comment: just tested this and it works a treat....have an issue with the code to create new though - it was working fine but now when if copies the array instead of copying to col a it is copying into col c - I am sure is us one of these but can't figure out what..  drrg.Resize(sarCount).Value = sarg.Value
        Set drrg = drrg.Offset(sarCount) , sarcount value is 3 - i tested by changing to 1 and made now difference

Comment: That's again VBasic's code that *you* said you got working in your previous question "*Brilliant just changed the First and last col values and bingo!! *". Is your FIRST_COLUMN = 4 (your D-column), and LAST_COLUMN = 12 (from what I can tell from the screenshot, O-column is your last)